# Cross-building a project dependent on different versions of specific library

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to build different versions of a project that depend on different versions of specific libraries. These library versions are compatible on a source level. So I want to build `com.company:myproject-mylib-1.0_2.12:1.0.0` that depends on `com.company:mylib:1.0` and `com.company:myproject-mylib-2.0_2.12:1.0.0` that depends on `com.company:mylib:2.0`. One of the ways I can think of is using environment variable to store library version, is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, one of these you have to set explicitly, then the other one can be calculated:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.company" % "mylib" % (if (name.value.endsWith("1.0")) "1.0" else "2.0")`
```

Then during build you could do something like:

```
sbt> ;compile;publish // <- e.g. for v 1.0
sbt> set name := "myproject-mylib-2.0"
sbt> ;compile;publish // <- e.g. for v 2.0
```

If you want it more principled you could define a new key:

```
val isNew = settingKey[Boolean]("Are we building a new version of a library")
Global / isNew := false

name := if (isNew.value) "myproject-mylib-2.0" else "myproject-mylib-1.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.company" % "mylib" % (if (isNew.value) "2.0" else "1.0")`
```

which you would build like

```
sbt> ;compile;publish // <- for v 1.0
sbt> set isNew := true
sbt> ;compile;publish // <- for v 2.0
```

or from command line

```
sbt compile publish "set isNew := true" compile publish
```